# Assertion failed: "Standard C++ Libraries Out of Range" && 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, uwp, hololens

I have some Problems with Unity 5.50.f3/Visual Studio 2015 for Windows Universal (HoloLens) and the Holograms 212 Tutorial( https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/holograms_212). T

If i started the Example inside the HoloLens Emulator or Device in Debug-Mode i got the following error code in Visual Studio and my App crashed:

```
    _CRT_ASSERT caught:
'''
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(73) : Assertion failed: "Standard C++ Libraries Out of Range" && 0

'''
```

I think the problem is that i **haven't** installed my Visual Studio at this path. Anyway it seemed to be (hardcoded?) inside the BridgeInterface.pdb, UnityEngineDelegates.pdb and UnityPlayer_UAP_x86_Debug_dotnet.pdb.
These files seemed to be used from Unity directory.

In Release-Mode this error didn't occur. Does any one has an idea how i can avoid this error?

Thank You :-)

Comment: The debug assertion indicates a bug, namely a `std::vector` access with an out-of-bounds index. You can only avoid the error by fixing it. The debug assertion dialog offered the option to *"Press Retry to debug the application"*. That's what you should do. It will take you straight to the location where the bug happens, including an entire call stack. That'll get you closer to fixing the bug.

Comment: There is no debug assertion dialog with the described option. Also the _DEBUG_ERROR("vector iterator not dereferencable"); does not show. The program execution stops only, so i couldn't find the location where the bug happens. I'think this is because the wrong VC directory path is set to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\vc\include\vector(73)" instead of my real installation path at "W:\Microsoft\Visual Studio 2015 Community\vc\include\vector(73)". But i did not find any option to change this path for a C# Universal project.